# TextInputLayout cannot add style

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Hi I tried to used TextInputLayout for my apps, at first it's worked but the problem came while I put 'style:' attribute and my app stopped working.

Here my code, I follow from AndroidDeveloper code and tried to put style

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Test"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with you code, show the CLASS too.

Comment: No class that i make before because i start a new activity